# Losing the error output from a command in the (set) element of batch file FOR statement

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, for-loop

I have a batch file that does a git pull on a git repository.  I want to see the output in the console window and in a log file.  I have a bunch of script code in the batch file to get me to the correct directory and then it runs the following:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f IN ('git pull --ff-only') DO (
    SET z=%%f
    ECHO   !z:^|=^^^|! 2>&1 | C:\Bin\tee.exe -a %logFile%
)
```

tee.exe is a little program the sends the output to the console and the specified log file.

This works fine as long as the git command succeeds.  I see the list of changed files, etc... in both the console and the log file.  However, if the git command generates an error, for example the pull would overwrite local changes, I see the following in the console window:

```
Pulling repository \GitHub\Dummy
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        Dummy/Dummy.Tests/Dummy.Tests.csproj
        Dummy/Dummy.Tests/packages.config
        Dummy/Dummy/Dummy.csproj
        Dummy/Dummy/packages.config
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
    Updating 8b9f90e..410251c
```

However, in the log file, I only see this:

```
Pulling repository \GitHub\Dummy
    Updating 8b9f90e..410251c
```

Is there a way to get the error information dumped to the log file?

Comment: Why using `for /F` here? why not simply doing this: `git pull --ff-only | C:\Bin\tee.exe -a C:\Bin\GitPull.log`, or, to get the error output also, `git pull --ff-only 2>&1 | C:\Bin\tee.exe -a C:\Bin\GitPull.log`?

Comment: Note: I corrected the original code.  I had pulled out some stuff just to be concise and it was too much.  The reason I use the /F is that the output of the git pull includes a pipe character ('|') and somewhere in the sequence of command that character is interpretted as an actual pipe operation and not just a text character.  So I had to escape it (as I am doing in the replaced code).

Answer (score 2):

`for` only handles STDOUT, not STDERR, so you have to redirect STDERR to STDOUT *inside* the `for` loop. When echoing `%%f`, it's already too late:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f IN ('git pull --ff-only 2^>^&1') DO (
    ECHO %%f| C:\Bin\tee.exe -a C:\Bin\GitPull.log
)
```

(and escape special chars like `<>&|,=`)

Comment: This is what I needed to do.  Thanks.